# Adding objects to instance variable array

Tags: ios, arrays, object, save, connection

Can someone help me out on this:

Im creating a property in my TableVC.m file :

```
@property NSMutableArray *savingBeaconSpecs;
```

In my Viewdidload I instantiate the array:

```
 NSMutableArray *savingBeaconSpecs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Now I do requests to the server, and I want to save the returned JSON into objects and save these each time in the array. So I did the following in the ConnectionDidFinishLaunching:

```
 self.artworkArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.data options:0 error:&err];
NSLog(@"Log ArtworkArray in ConnectionDidFinishLoading%@", self.artworkArray);
```

And:

```
Artwork *artwork = [[Artwork alloc]init];
artwork.title = [self.artworkArray valueForKey:@"name"];
artwork.artist = [[self.artworkArray objectForKey:@"artist"] valueForKey:@"name"];
artwork.CreationYear = [self.artworkArray valueForKey:@"creationYear"];
artwork.categorie = [[self.artworkArray objectForKey:@"exposition"] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Now I want to save this object into the savingBeaconSpecs NSMutableArray

```
[self.savingBeaconSpecs addObject:artwork];
```

But the NSMUtableArray savingBeaconSpecs always returns 0 when i try log his content

Anyone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To instantiate the array, you should do:

`self.savingBeaconSpecs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

or equally good:

`self.savingBeaconSpecs = [NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 1):

Because you declare it locally in your viewDidLoad :

```
NSMutableArray *savingBeaconSpecs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

you should use

```
 self.savingBeaconSpecs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and

```
[self.savingBeaconSpecs addObject:artwork];
```

and declare your property as (without the first capital S)

```
@property NSMutableArray *savingBeaconSpecs;
```